# Compress image at client side (angularjs) and upload to server(nodejs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, image, compression

I am using **ng-file-upload** directive to upload files to nodejs in my application. Now, I am trying to compress the image before uploading. To do that I have tried using **compress** method of **Java Image Compress(JIC)** library. It is successfully compressing an image. Now, the problem is, I have to send a file object to my server(nodejs) but **compress** method returns an image with **src** attribute. Is there any way to get file object with url? or any other alternative way of achieving compress at angularjs and upload to nodejs? Any help appreciated.

Comment: According to your description, you have JRE on the client site. Could not you upload it to your node server right after compression from java?

Comment: I could not... It says 'request entity too large' as I am trying to upload src attribute

Answer (score 5):

I think [ng-image-compress](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-image-compress) will solve your issue. To use this,

- Download ng-image-compress
- Bower - bower install angular-image-compress.
- Include angular.js and angular-image-compress.js in your application 
  and add ngImageCompress as dependency to your main module.

angular.module('myApp', ['ngImageCompress']);

Then you can include "**resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" ng-image-compress** " in your File Type input to compress your image.

You can find more details from https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress

Comment: Updated my answer, I think this will help.

Comment: image compressed i agree but now how you will send it in post request

Answer (score 0):

set req headers 
`Content-Encoding: gzip`
it will be compressed automatically

Comment: It may not be useful for this, I need to do client side image compression where if user tries to upload a large file, it need to be compressed at client side only.i.e before uploading to the server

Comment: @pydev are u using node-webkit or it is in browser

Comment: it is in browser, I am developing a meanstack application